# Redux store undefined on page refresh

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router

By getting the `currentUser` from the redux store, I authorize the react router.

There's no problem switching between pages, but when I refresh the page that requires authorization, I can't authorize it because the `currentUser` comes undefined.

**componentDidMount**

```
 componentDidMount(){
    this.props.actions.getCurrentUser()
  }
```

**Router**

```
  <Route exact path="/profile/:id/settings" render={(props) => {
            var urlId = props.match.params.id;
        return this.props.isLogged ? this.props.currentUser.id == urlId ? < ProfileSettings {...props} /> : <Redirect to={"/profile/" + urlId} /> : <Redirect to="/" />;
          }
   } />
```

**react-redux**

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    actions: {
      getCurrentUser: bindActionCreators(authAsyncActions.getCurrentUserApi, dispatch)
    }
  }
}
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    isLogged: state.isLoggedReducer,
    currentUser: state.currentUserReducer
  }
}
```

**getCurrentUserApi**

```
export function getCurrentUserApi() {
    return async (dispatch, getState) => {
        if (localStorageHelper.isExistsToken()) {
            if (Object.keys(getState().currentUserReducer).length == 0) {
                await axios.get(CURRENT_USER_PATH, {
                    headers: localStorageHelper.authHeaderObj()
                }).then(res => {
                    dispatch(authActionsCreators.currentUserSuccess(res.data))
                    dispatch(authActionsCreators.isLoggedTSuccess())
                }).catch(err => {
                    if (err.response.status === 401) {
                        var refreshToken = bindActionCreators(refreshTokenApi, dispatch)
                        refreshToken();
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ` this.props.actions.getCurrentUser()` this should in your useEffect. This should not be used, how you have used it. Post your full code or create a sandbox.

Comment: I didn't use hooks I used class component

Comment: then that function should be in your `componentDidMount`. Try creating a sandbox.

Comment: Tried but still gets undefined.

Comment: In which container are you calling `this.props.actions.getCurrentUser()`? If the action does get dispatched, you are probably facing the problem that this is an asynchronous action. There are multiple ways to solve that, for example by using a wrapping component which doesn't render the routes when the currentUser call is in the loading state.

Comment: Yes you are right. I thought something like that too.
Is there a tool that does not render the component until I load the `currentUser` ?
How can I do that. Thank you.

Comment: I'm doing this call from the top component. `App.js`